# Setting form value data according to model attribute in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to take input of time and timeUnit(day/minutes). If minutes is supported then I have to show drop-down else only text showing days to user. In mmentioned `<div>` 2, I want to set form-field `timeUnit` according to model attribute selectedTimeUnit. Can someone provide help I am new to angular. Thanks in advance.

```
<div>
   <div class="div-table-col" *ngIf="!isMinutesAllowed()"> Enter time data
      <input type="number" min="1" step="1" formControlName="period">
      <select  formControlName="timeUnit" [(ngModel)]="selectedTimeUnit">
        <option *ngFor="let unit of getTimeUnits()" [ngValue]="unit">{{unit}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="div-table-col" *ngIf="isMinutesAllowed()"> Enter time data
      <input type="number" min="1" step="1" formControlName="period">
      {{ selectedTimeUnit == 'DAYS' ? 'days' : 'minutes' }}
   </div>
</div>
```

###########APPLIED THIS HACK NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT##########

I have added input field with type hidden. I am not sure if its the correct approach but its working per need.

```
<div> 
  <div class="div-table-col" *ngIf="!isMinutesAllowed()"> Players who have been inactive for past
      <input type="number" min="1" step="1" formControlName="periodOfInactivity">
      <select  formControlName="timeUnit" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeriodOfActivityTimeUnit">
        <option *ngFor="let unit of getTimeUnit()" [ngValue]="unit">{{unit}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-col" *ngIf="isMinutesAllowed()"> Players who have been inactive for past
      <input type="number" min="1" step="1" formControlName="periodOfInactivity">
      {{ selectedPeriodOfActivityTimeUnit == 'DAYS' ? 'days' : 'minutes' }}
      <input type="hidden" formControlName="timeUnit" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeriodOfActivityTimeUnit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the typescript potion of your code

Comment: I have added input with hidden type, I am not sure if its the right way to do it but its working as need.

Answer (score 0):

I think your *ngIf should not a method, it should be.

```
<div class="div-table-col" *ngIf="!isMinutesAllowed"> Enter time data
      <input type="number" min="1" step="1" formControlName="period">
      <select  formControlName="timeUnit" [(ngModel)]="selectedTimeUnit">
        <option *ngFor="let unit of getTimeUnits()" [ngValue]="unit">{{unit}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col" *ngIf="isMinutesAllowed"> Enter time data
      <input type="number" min="1" step="1" formControlName="period">
      {{ selectedTimeUnit == 'DAYS' ? 'days' : 'minutes' }}
    </div>
```

Comment: here *ngIf is working as expected i.e. if minutesAllowed then it will be dropdown else it will be simple text. The problem I am facing here is that first div element working fine and setting formControlName="timeUnit" as expected. The problem I am facing when minutes are not allowed then I am not able to set "timeUnit" value according to selectedTimeUnit attribute.

Comment: **NEVER** use in the same tag `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName`, a little cat die when you do it.